# Selecting multiple elements for "nextArrow" in Slick slider

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm trying to apply two separate elements to the nextArrow function in a slick slider.
But I do not get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
 $('.slick-container').slick({
infinite: false,
edgeFriction: 0,
prevArrow: false,
nextArrow: $('.button-next') && $('.button-right'),
dots: true,
customPaging : function() {
  return '<span class="slick-dot"></span>'
} });
```

I thought a **&&** or a **||** would work to apply the nextArrow function to both. But I assume that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a concatenated JQuery response object from the two query responses or use a single query that achieves that result by [CSS Selector Lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#selector_lists) (like `$('.button-next, .button-right`)`). I would recommend using selector lists; it's a more straightforward/simple approach.

`&&` and `||` are boolean logic operators in JavaScript. They do not do array concatenation.